# Ember.js need help on collection handler for simple Todo example

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to Ember.js , i was trying a simple examples on Ember.js, till now fine , but im stuck with this example.

here i paste the Todo example i have created.

JS:-

```
    App = Ember.Application.create();

    App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
     });

     App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
       templateName:"appTemp"
     });

    App.Todo = Ember.Object.extend({
      title:null
    });

     App.TodoController =Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
       content: [],
      addItem: function(title){
            var todo = App.Todo.create({title: title})  ;
            this.pushObject(todo);
           }
     });

      App.TodoController.addItem("hello");
      App.TodoController.addItem("world");

    App.TodoAddView = Ember.View.extend({
       createTodo: function(name){
         App.TodoController.addItem(document.getElementById("todoName").value);
     }
   });

   App.TodoView = Ember.View.extend();

   App.TodosListView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
     itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    })
   });
```

Html: printing the todo items script

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="appTemp">
  {{#collection App.TodosListView contentBinding = "App.TodoController" }}
  {{#view App.TodoView contentBinding="content"}}
  <label>TODO - {{content.title}}</label>
  {{/view}}
  {{/collection}}
</script>
```

So the problem is

Im showing all the added Todos like below

TODO - [todoName]

**but it is not printing the todoName properly**

so im not able to identify ,what is the mistake i have made here.

```
   <label>TODO - {{content.title}}</label>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a good reason to use CollectionView? It might be easier to use the {{#each}} helper (more readable imho). Therefore alternative proposals:

**Using the each helper and an inline template:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="appTemp">
  {{#each todo in App.TodoController }}
  {{#view App.TodoView contextBinding="todo"}}
   <label>TODO - {{title}}</label>
  {{/view}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

**Using the each helper without inline template:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="appTemp">
  {{#each todo in App.TodoController }}
  {{view App.TodoView contextBinding="todo"}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todoView">
  <label>TODO - {{title}}</label>
</script/>
```

As you see i am also proposing to **use the contextBinding for your View**. You should always use **the content property for controllers**, whereas **Views should always use the context property**. This is the more emberish way of doing it. As you see in this case, you do not need to specify a prefix before your attribute path ({{title}} instead of {{context.title}}). This approach makes the View more reusable, since if will also work when used with controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your template to:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="appTemp">
  {{#collection App.TodosListView contentBinding="App.TodoController"}}
    {{#view App.TodoView}}
      <label>TODO - {{title}}</label>
    {{/view}}
  {{/collection}}
</script>
```

See http://jsbin.com/iriwow/1/edit